# AWS Cloud Watch Alarm script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to create script which should make sending email notifications from AWS Cloudwatch whenever instance is unhealthy or down. I am new in the AWS world, so can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: cloudwatch has integration to SNS. when you create a cloudwatch alarm, you can set up an alarm notification as well.

Comment: Here is a reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ConsoleAlarms.html